# Spring AOP. Advice in one transaction with target

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aspectj, spring-aop

I have Spring aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect
```

with @Around advice for service method

```
@Around("execution(* some.pack.SomeService.someMethod(..))")
    public Object triggerSome(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        //pre-processing
        Object res = pjp.proceed();
        additionalService.additionalAction();
        return res;
    }
```

All methods (SomeService.someMethod and AdditionalService.additionalAction) are @Transactional methods. I search a solution to execute this methods in one transaction. When [aditionalAction] method is fail changes added by [someMethod] must be rollbacked.

Adding the @Transactional annotation to the advice method is not working. Using of @Order annotation for configure transaction manager and aspects does not give that I need.

Is it possible to invoking this methods in one transaction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a third Method on your **Service**  and Mark it as `@Transactional`.

```
@Transactional
Object thirdMethod(){
   Object res = pjp.proceed();
   additionalService.additionalAction();
   return res;
}
```

and call it from your Aspect:

```
    @Around("execution(* some.pack.SomeService.someMethod(..))")
    public Object triggerSome(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        //pre-processing
        return thirdMethod();
    }
```

Comment: And pass the ProceedingJoinPoint through a thirdMethod parameter? Yes, I thought about it, but was hoping that there is more flexible and  solution) Thanks for you answer.

Comment: @medvedmike the most convenient way is to keep  transactional methods within a service.there is no more convenient way than that.

Comment: Ok, I'll take it. Thanks.

Comment: Object res = pjp.proceed(); int 1=1/0;
   additionalService.additionalAction();  I try to add 1/0 in the middle,but it was not Transactional